# File input filters in mvc4 or html 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I know that we can use filter types in HTML 5 with accept attribute  `<input accept="audio/*|video/*|image/*|MIME_type">`

But these all things are showing "All Files" options too. I want strict to certain file types in the like "*.pdf, All office word types, images, excel".

How can we do that?

My Code like

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Attachment, new { @class = "form-control", type = "file" })
```

Answer (score 5):

You simply replace your accept(s) with the full mime type in your case application/pdf rather than the wildcard *.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Attachment, new { @class = "form-control", type = "file", accept="application/pdf" })
```

You can separated multiple mime type with a comma, if you wanted pdf and word in a single upload control you would do so like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Attachment, new { @class = "form-control", type = "file", accept="application/pdf, application/msword" })
```

**Update**

If you store your accepted mime types in a collection (hard-coded here for demo purposes)

```
private List<string> mimeTypes = new List<string> {
        "application/pdf", 
        "application/msword"
    };
```

You can add the accepted mime type to your model, return them like this:

```
model.MimeTypes = string.Join(", ", mimeTypes);
```

Render them like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Attachment, new { @class = "form-control", type = "file", accept=Model.MimeTypes })
```

Comment: what about if I want "pdf, word, excel, jpg, gif", but not all files??

Comment: You can simply append them but separate them with a comma i.e. application/pdf, application/vnd.ms-word.document

Comment: I would also make sure you check them server-side too for security reasons.

Comment: You have to pick your mime-types depending on the file extensions, this is for word docs with .doc extension. http://jsfiddle.net/VCdvA/1062/ Is that any good for you?

Comment: this is good.. It is still showing me "All Files" in dropdown list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46703/discussion-between-hutchonoid-and-james123)

Comment: Just for information, you need `images/png` if you only want to display pictures in png format. I found this topic searching for this, and this complete the answer.